# how to combine csv and json data in single dataframe pysaprk

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I dont have any idea if this question is asked before, but I am asking anyway.

suppose I have a json file and csv file with both having same fields as `{"string":"string1","int":1,"array":[1,2,3],"dict": {"key": "value1"}}`

and same column names in csv file as `string,int,array,dict`.

What I am expecting to do is combine both the data into one daraframe with single line of code.

I know the other way read them saperately and combine after, but this seems something different . I have tried my turn if anyone want to give it a thought.

Comment: Have you tried unionAll ?

Comment: How is your csv data ? `ArrayType` and `MapType` are not supported as such by spark CSV reader. Could you provide sample data ?

Comment: I have added a sample string above, but for case assume any data format you have and the same data format follows for json too. like suppose for only three columns in csv as name , dob and address and say we have same feilds in json file too. my question is how can we merge this data with single fetch inside single dataframe. and when I say single dataframe , I mean something like this df=read.json.csv('path'). Is this possible or not is what I am trying to figure out? @MaFF

Comment: @Fabich thanks for your reply , yes I tried it and it works but I am trying to figure out a way to do this in a single fetch. Can you help with this problem statement.